# LinkedList java Iterator.next concept?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have trouble with the LinkedList concept. I don't know how the `iterator.next` stores the reference of next node.here is code
This is Node class

```
public class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data= data;
    }
}
```

This is LinkedList class

```
public class LL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node start = new Node(0);

            Node iterator =start;

            for(int i =1; i <5 ;i++) {
                iterator  =iterator.next = new Node(i);
            }

                    for(iterator = start ; iterator != null;  iterator = iterator .next){
                    System.out.println(iterator .data);
                    }
        }
    }
```

Please tell me what `iterator.next` does when next is just an object of type `Node`.

Comment: `iterator.next` is a reference to a Node, it has no other purpose.  This is what the value stores. What is your doubt?

Comment: what is purpose of next? next is same for all iterations then why refrence is being changed as
iterator =item.next; 
is executing.?

Comment: Please *please* try to spell your questions correctly. You are not helping who's reading them.

Comment: @cuteprogrammer *"next is same for all iterations"* and why do you think that?

Comment: Your code is just iterating through nodes. In order to advance to and print the next node, `iterator`'s reference must be changed to the `next` node. For example, if you have nodes 1 through 4, node 1's `next` would reference node 2. Node 2's `next` would contain reference to node 3. etc etc. You would really benefit by reading up one some tutorials/documentation on  Linked Lists.

Comment: In that example, `next` is always `null`, but with more code you would find that `next = somethingSomewhere;` so it will be different.

Comment: Try this article: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html

Comment: Tom! actually "next" is not being change just like iterator.please clear my concept.

Comment: `Node next` within an object of class Node refers to a value that is capable of storing a reference to a Node object. So, the first Node uses its `next` field to refer (or "point to") the second Node, which in turn points to the third, and so on. A Node not meant to point to its successor has `null` stored in its `next` field. (Basically, these references are just computer memory addresses, but you might as well forget this and revert to more abstract thinking.) - Note that `Node next` does not contain a `Node` data object - this would result in an impossible recursion. It's just a *reference*

Comment: I know it is just a reference.can you  tell me what is (sample value/sample address) is being generated in next object after iterations.

Answer (score 0):

From your example seems your Node structure looks smth like this :

```
class Node {
    Object item; // some kind of value
    Node next; // reference to some other node
}
```

so each reference of type Node, can hold a reference to another object of type Node, that can hold a reference to another object of type Node,... creating a structure similar to a linked list.

Your code just goes throught that structure in the way I described above:

- we have a reference to an object of type Node, called `iterator`
- as long as the iterator reference is not null

  - we print the item in the current Node, `iterator.item`
  - we make iterator point to the next Node reference, `iterator = iterator.next`

Answer (score 0):

It's often best to think of datastructures visually.  here for example is a linked list with 3 nodes:

[A] -> [B] -> [C]

Calling next() on the node is just returning the next node in the list.

for example in pseudocode
A.next() == B
and
B.next() == C

You can read more about LinkedLists and see more pictures here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list